# How to compare BuiltinByteStrings onchain?

Tags: plutus, on-chain

I want to check **on-chain** if a given `TokenName` is of a specific pattern, for example:

- `aaa1`
- `aaa2`
- `aaa3`

I have something like this, but it throws an interpreter exception:

```
checkValidMint :: TokenName -> Integer -> Bool
checkValidMint tn count  = tn == (TokenName $ "aaa" <> (integerToByteString count))

integerToByteString :: Integer -> BuiltinByteString
integerToByteString n
    | n == 0 = "0"
    | n == 1 = "1"
    | n == 2 = "2"
    | n == 3 = "3"
    | n == 4 = "4"
    | n == 5 = "5"
    | n == 6 = "6"
    | n == 7 = "7"
    | n == 8 = "8"
    | n == 9 = "9"
    | otherwise = integerToByteString (n `P.divide` 10) P.<> integerToByteString (n `P.modulo` 10)
```

**Update 2**
Also tried:

```
integerToByteString n
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 0) = "0"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 1) = "1"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 2) = "2"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 3) = "3"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 4) = "4"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 5) = "5"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 6) = "6"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 7) = "7"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 8) = "8"
            | (Builtins.equalsInteger n 9) = "9"
            | otherwise = integerToByteString (n `PlutusTx.Prelude.divide` 10) PP.<> integerToByteString (n `PlutusTx.Prelude.modulo` 10)
```

I keep getting an interpreter error:

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Use of Haskell Integer equality, possibly via the Haskell Eq typeclass Context: Compiling expr: GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger# Context: Compiling expr: GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger# x Context: Compiling expr: GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger# x y Context: Compiling expr: case GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger# x y of wild [Occ=Once] { __DEFAULT -> GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ GHC.Types.Bool wild } Context: Compiling expr: \ (y [Occ=Once] :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer) -> case GHC.Integer.Type.eqInteger# x y of ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've done the integer conversion in the past. Might need some minor updating:

```
{-# INLINEABLE intToString #-}
intToString :: Integer -> Builtins.String
intToString i = Prelude.foldr Builtins.appendString "" strings
  where
    ints = intToInts i
    strings = map (Builtins.charToString . intToChar) ints


{-# INLINEABLE intToChar #-}
intToChar :: Integer -> Haskell.Char
intToChar i
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 0) = '0'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 1) = '1'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 2) = '2'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 3) = '3'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 4) = '4'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 5) = '5'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 6) = '6'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 7) = '7'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 8) = '8'
  | (Builtins.equalsInteger i 9) = '9'
  | otherwise = '0' -- Fix this
```

Then instead of `checkValidMint`, you can just check that the expected amount of your new token is included in the output value in the policy `ctx`, like [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/c4cc9ee1add8f421e57789befb6a0c90621801f1/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Uniswap/OnChain.hs#L105) in the Uniswap example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get this code to run. It seems like `charToString` is not part of the API anymore. And String has been replaced with `BuiltinString`.

I am not sure how to make use of this code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are using `INLINEABLE` on your code, try using `equalsInteger` instead of `==`, and see where that lands you. You might need to dig and see what methods on `char` there are instead of `charToString`. I'd need to do some digging to say for sure what all has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout the utils package I used for the open source cardano lottery located here: https://github.com/lley154/cardano-lottery/blob/main/src/Utils.hs.   This code has been tested and works on the testnet.

Also, there was a similar post that may help if you having issues and need to be aware of the encoding of builtinbytestrings in plutus.  [How to get a base 16 hex BuiltinString from getTxId](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/how-to-get-a-base-16-hex-builtinstring-from-gettxid/7805#7805)

Answer (score 0):

After testing out many different variations, changing imports to make sure the correct functions of `Prelude` and `PlutusTx.Prelude` are used, I've found the problem:

1. I made sure this pragma is present: `{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}`
2. I imported both Preludes in a qualified way:

```
import           PlutusTx.Prelude as PP
import           Prelude          as P
```

which let's me clearly distinguish what operators to use when it comes to `Integer` comparisons. I subsequently replaces all `==` with either `PP.==` for **on-chain** and `P.==` for **off-chain** code.

3. Lastly, I found one more error where I used Integer pattern matching **on-chain** like so:

```
checkMint :: String -> Integer -> Bool
checkMint s (1)  = ...
checkMint s (-1) = ...
checkMint _ _    = False
```

The pattern matching seems to default to `P.==` for this **on-chain** code, so I replace it with an *if-then-else* and it worked fine.

```
checkMint s amt = 
    if amt PP.== 1 then ... 
    else if amt PP.== -1 then ... 
    else ...
```